# How to load textures for obj?

Tags: aframe, webvr

I'm trying to load an .obj which has several .jpgs as textures.  My .obj is rendering - but without applying the material.

The .mtl looks like

```
newmtl material_0
Ka 0.200000 0.200000 0.200000
Kd 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Ks 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Tr 1.000000
illum 2
Ns 0.000000
map_Kd tex_0.jpg
```

I assume the path to the .jpgs are correct - if I change it, I see 404 errors in the console.

My aframe code is:

```
 <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
           <a-asset-item id="moore-obj" src="obj/moore.obj"></a-asset-item>
           <a-asset-item id="moore-mtl" src="obj/moore.obj.mtl"></a-asset-item>
     </a-assets>
     <a-entity
          obj-model="obj: #moore-obj; mtl: #moore-mtl"
          scale="1 1 1"
          rotation="0 0 0"
          position="1 1 1"></a-entity>
 </a-scene>
```

The 3D model appears in the scene - but there are no textures overlayed on it.  I'm running this on localhost, and I'm not seeing any CORS warnings.

The object is http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:36415

Comment: That's interesting. Everything looks square at first glance. What type of local server are you running?

Comment: Python simple HTTP server. I'm wondering if it is something to do with the object size?

Comment: What's the URL for the 404 that you're seeing? I'm guessing it's just a matter of making sure that tex_0.jpg is in the correct folder. It should be in the same location as the mtl file.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out to be an issue with that particular OBJ file. It uses three materials but it doesn't define object groups for the sub-objects that use each of those materials, so Three.js' OBJLoader doesn't associate the materials correctly.

You can work around it by adding group lines before each `usemtl` line in the obj file.

For example:

```
g g_0
usemtl material_0
...
g g_1
usemtl material_1
```

etc.